# DELETE SQL transaction not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, html

I am trying to clear my html5 local sql database but for some reason it is not working. Please see my code below: my alert always shows that length is > 0, does anyone know why?

```
function clearHistory(){
db.transaction( function(tx){
    tx.executeSql('DELETE * FROM history', []);
});

db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM history', [], function (tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length, i;
        alert ("length=" + len);
    });
});
}
```

Comment: @Arran the html5 tag, and use of websql syntax clearly show that this is using a local database. I don't think there is even a concept of sql injection because the user can at any time just delete the entire database.

Comment: Look for error management functions and check what errors your current `DELETE` statement is issuing. That way you can judge what's wrong by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the *
    DELETE FROM history

Comment: Yep, you only have to specify `DELETE FROM table_name;`

Answer (score 0):

Change your delete statement to:

```
DELETE FROM History
```

or even

```
DELETE History
```

You could even use `TRUNCATE TABLE`, this uses less system resources and transaction log resources, however it will reset the seed on any IDENTITY columns you may have.

Answer (score -6):

it is because you should NEVER call SQL from JavaScript.  EVER !!  encapsulate your SQL calls in some WS API and call that from JS.

Comment: Should of been a comment, is probably what the downvotes are for.

Comment: He is using a local database stored in the browser. This is a feature of HTML5 - not a server-side database.

Comment: @Arran the downvotes are not because it should've been a comment. It's because @ \foampile thought this was about a server-side SQL call.